# Incorrect Signature in XAML button clicked event

Tags: xaml, resharper

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Resharper 2018.2. I am getting an "Incorrect Signature" error when resharper looks at my code.

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonNext" 
        BackgroundColor="#bebebe"
        CornerRadius="5"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Text="Next" 
        TextColor="#FFFFFF"
        Clicked="ButtonNextClickedAsync"></Button>
```

[image]

Signature is

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ButtonNextClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

It only gives this error when the method is async. Does anyone know what the correct signature is?

Comment: Can you add the signature you are using to your question?

Comment: @PatrickHollweck forgot to add it! now there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the signature to:

```
private async void ButtonNextClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Then call your task inside this event handler.

Comment: Excellent! I forgot that "async void" is to be used for Event Handlers (and only event handlers). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx